# "Taller FROM when I last saw her" vs "Taller THAN when I last saw her"

Tags: conjunctions, comparison

Today I saw a photo of my friend's daughter, whom I saw in person more than a year ago. She looks to have grown about a foot since then.

Would it have been grammatically correct of me to say, "She's a foot taller from when I last saw her"?

How about "She's a foot taller than when I last saw her"? This seems less accurate since height ("taller") and time ("when") aren't comparable.

How about using both: "She's a foot taller than from when I last saw her"? This means she is taller than she was at the time I last saw her.

Stylistically, I prefer the first one--"taller from when I last saw her"--but is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Taller **than** [some other height, e.g. the height she was when you last saw her).

Comment: Thanks, Michael. But "some other height" isn't mentioned. Also, if I say "taller from when I last saw her," isn't that acceptable because it's just a rewording of "From when I last saw her, she was taller"?

Comment: "But "some other height" isn't mentioned." Doesn't have to be 'mentioned'. It is implied by (1) taller than (2) when I last saw her.

Comment: Well, at any rate, can't "taller from when I last saw her" also be used? That's what I'm mainly concerned with.

Comment: No, you can't use **from**.

Comment: How would you reword this sentence: "From when I last saw her, she was taller"?

Comment: I would reword it to 'She was taller than when I last saw her'.

Comment: @thechristophershow *From* is not suitable and sounds out of place.  You are looking for the word *since*, which allows a comparison over time without using *than*.  She was taller *since* I last saw her.  *Than*, however, is still the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Comparative adjectives (e.g. taller, shorter, bigger, smaller, etc) are used with **than**. Not 'from'.

> Comparative adjectives compare one person or thing with another and
>   enable us to say whether a person or thing has more or less of a
>   particular quality:
>
> Josh is taller than his sister.
>
> I’m more interested in music than sport.
>
> Big cars that use a lot of petrol are less popular now than twenty
>   years ago.

[Comparison (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting)

> than
>
> preposition, conjunction
>
> used to join two parts of a comparison

[Than (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/than)

Comment: Yes, but I want to use "taller" to compare her current height now and her height in the past. In other words, "From the time I last saw her, she is taller." That's a rephrasing of "She is taller than from when I last saw her," right? In the latter sentence, "from" seems necessary because without it, you're comparing height ("taller") and time ("when"), which you can't do. Yet "than from," though grammatically correct in this case (right?), sounds ugly.

Comment: You can compare something with a time: she is taller than when I last saw her; the water is colder than when I filled the bath; gasoline is cheaper than last week. If you want, you can imagine "she was", "it was", and "it was" after "than" in each of those, but you don't need them.

Comment: I know people do compare things with times, but is that technically correct? Or is it considered casual, colloquial? "She is taller than when I last saw her" literally means someone is tall, and the time is less tall. "The water is colder than when I filled the bath" literally means the water is cold, and the time is less cold. Logically it makes absolutely zero sense. Sometimes English grammar is like that, of course, but is this one of those cases? Or is this a case of casual writing, like blogging or something, and something you shouldn't use in a serious novel?

Comment: Continuing from my above comment, I know "than" is "used to join two parts of a comparison," but that's assuming the two parts are of the same category. For example, in "Taller than me," you're comparing the _height_ of two people. "Taller than when" means you're comparing the _height_ of one person with a _place_ _in_ _time_. Something tells me Fowler would hate it. Can a place in time be either short or tall? Does time have height?

Comment: Your comment two comments above this, Michael, helped clarify it for me. Thanks, I get it now. But I wonder if your comment directly above this one, about abbreviations, was meant for another thread.

Comment: @thechristophershow You are not comparing something with a place in time.  You are comparing two things to each other and noting that their difference occurred over time.  Once again English is dropping words.  To better understand Michael's comment, note the dropped words.  "Gasoline is cheaper than [it was] last week.   She is taller than [she was] last time I saw her."  You're comparing the subject of your sentence to itself and then specifying an elapsed time period over which the change occurred.  In such usages we may, and often do, drop the second reference to the subject.